# parent calling abstract method in python

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, python-3.x

I'm new to python. I want to define some abstract methods in my parent class and use them. I wrote a code like this

```
class BaseListAPI(APIView):
    __metaclass__  = abc.ABCMeta

    def get(self, request):
        search_object, start, count = 
        tools.handlers.read_get_request_data(request.GET)
        order_by = request.GET.get('order_by')

        return get_successful_response(self.get_query_set.list(
            without_user_serializer=self.get_serializer,
            search_object=search_object,
            start=start,
            count=count,
            order_by=order_by
        ))

    @abc.abstractmethod
    def get_query_set(self):
        """Method that should do something."""

    @abc.abstractmethod
    def get_serializer(self):
        """this method gets the serializer"""


class TourListListAPI(BaseListAPI):
    def get_query_set(self):
        return models.Tour.objects

    def get_serializer(self):
        return without_user.TourSerializer
```

When i call `self.get_query_set()` for example i expect the child function call but it never get called instead abstract parent methods getting called witch results in an error!! What i'm missing here?

Comment: As far as I can tell your code should just work, so the problem is in a part you didn't post. Please post the calling code (well the minimum required to trigger the error that is), the full matching traceback, and add the missing imports in your snippet - I assume `APIView` is from django-rest-framework but that's a wild guess.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just made a silly mistake! It wasn't working because it didn't put parentheses when calling functions is parent class! now this work like a charm.

```
class BaseListAPI(APIView):
    __metaclass__  = abc.ABCMeta

    def get(self, request):
        search_object, start, count = 
        tools.handlers.read_get_request_data(request.GET)
        order_by = request.GET.get('order_by')

        return get_successful_response(self.get_query_set().list(
            without_user_serializer=self.get_serializer(),
            search_object=search_object,
            start=start,
            count=count,
            order_by=order_by
        ))

    @abc.abstractmethod
    def get_query_set(self):
        """Method that should do something."""

    @abc.abstractmethod
    def get_serializer(self):
        """this method gets the serializer"""
```